# How to debug issues with my binary search function in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

First of all I need a calculation for when the looked for number is greater then the number "landed" on. (less and I can just use /2 but I don't know what to do when it's the other way since I use int and not double.)

Secondly I'm getting an out of bounds error which I don't know the cause of.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BinärSökning {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer[] otherList = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        listA.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherList));

        String lts = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which number between 1 and 10 are you looking for? ");
        int lt = Integer.parseInt(lts);

        int s = listA.size()/2;

        while(true){
            if(lt==listA.get(s)){

                System.out.println("Number found in position " + s);

            }if(lt<listA.get(s)){

                s = ???;

            }else{

                s = s/2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for binary search is not quite the way your wrote it.
Here's the first result from google: 
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code retrofitted with the correct binary search algorithm taken from the link which George mentioned.

```
int lo = 0;
int hi = listA.size - 1;
while (lo <= hi) {
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

    if (lt < listA.get(mid)) {
        hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (lt > listA.get(mid)) {
        lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number found in position ", mid);
    }
}
```

The algorithm keeps halving the sorted array of numbers depending on whether the number at `mid` is greater or less than the input value `lt`.  Also, you should provide some error handling in case the user input cannot be found in the sorted array.